# How to force GCMRegistrar unregister?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am not able unregister GCMRegistrar. I was trying in my code to run by:

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
```

and also

```
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext(), false);
```

and also

```
Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
startService(unregIntent);
```

I get notification even when I clear data/cache of my app and this app is killed but not UNINSTALLED. (I checked in DDMS too).

Unfortunatelly I am not able paste my code due copyright company.
Did someone had the same issue?

Comment: Does your app re-register when it starts? You also have to make sure that you are unregistering from your servers as well.

Comment: yeah there could be a problem on server side but i don't have access to it, thanks